# Visual Studio 2008, drop down menu item not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, menu, menuitem, drop-down-menu

I'm beating my head against the wall trying to figure this out. I have a horizontal menu on my GUI, and set the helpMenuItem to be invisible for a few minutes. I set it to visible again, and now, when I hover/click on the helpMenuItem, it doesn't display the drop down menu items. The other menu items drop downs work fine, this is the only one that won't display a drop down with the appropriate "userManualMenuItem" inside.

I've tried rebuilding, cleaning, and closing and reopening visual studio, those haven't helped. Below is an example of the Help button in my menu, and the drop down menu item "User Manual", that won't show. Also, the visual studio generated code for the items in question.

Thanks for any help.

---

File | Edit | Help
................| User Manual |

---

```
        // 
        // helpMenuItem
        // 
        this.helpMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
           this.userManualMenuItem});
        this.helpMenuItem.Name = "helpMenuItem";
        this.helpMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(44, 20);
        this.helpMenuItem.Text = "Help";
        // 
        // userManualMenuItem
        // 
        this.userManualMenuItem.Name = "userManualMenuItem";
        this.userManualMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(152, 22);
        this.userManualMenuItem.Text = "User Manual";
        this.userManualMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.userManualMenuItem_Click);
        // 
        // menu
        // 
        this.menu.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
           this.fileMenuItem,
           this.setupMenuItem,
           this.subcontractorsMenuItem,
           this.reportsMenuItem,
           this.windowMenuItem,
           this.helpMenuItem});
        this.menu.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.menu.Name = "menu";
        this.menu.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(714, 24);
        this.menu.TabIndex = 4;
        this.menu.Text = "menu";
```

EDIT: I made another menu item in the helpMenuItem, and it appeared when I ran the program. The other "userManualMenuItem" was still not showing up, however. I then deleted the old userManualMenuItem from the GUI, and renamed the new one to the same "userManualMenuItem", and after opening the program again, it did not show up. It seems that there is a problem with the menu item itself, and not the help drop down menu item...

Comment: Can you show the code that you use to hide/show the menu item?

Comment: Nothing is strange in the above snippet, I suggest that you add an event listner for the VisibleChanged Event on your userManualMenuItem and then set a break point, once reached, try to walk through the call stack to find the line of code causing the menu to disappear

Comment: Found it. Some stray code that Visual Studio generated and for some reason, didn't delete when I changed the status of the visible field. Thanks for the tip Waleed. If you'd like to formulate your comment into an answer, I'd be happy to accept it as the solution to my problem.

Comment: happy for you, I'm formulating it as an answer :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is strange in the above snippet, I suggest that you add an event listner for the VisibleChanged Event on your userManualMenuItem and then set a break point, once reached, try to walk through the call stack to find the line of code causing the menu to disappear.